# Python code issue. I have made a simple lottery system using python. How to stop variable b in resetting to 1000 every-time?

Tags: python, function, variables, reset

In the mentioned code, variable b was used to denote my account balance. How it should work is, initially account balance must be 1000.For every play,100 has to be deducted, if won, should get 900 and if lost must lose 100. All must happen in and around b. But b always gets reset to 1000. Why is it so?

```
def rand(k,b):
  import random
  b = b-100
  print("Rs. 100 deducted to buy the ticket. Your present account balance is", b)
  n = random.randint(1,10)
  print("The lottery number that won the price is", n)
  if (k == n):
    b = b+900
    print("Wow, congrats. You won. Here is Rs. 900. Your present account balance is Rs.", b)
  else:
    b =b-100
    print("Shit, you just lost your Rs. 100. Your present account balance is Rs.", b)
  return b


b= 1000
a=0
while(1):
  k = int(input("Enter your coupon number choice from 1-10 to play or enter 000 to exit. Each play costs Rs. 100"))
  if (k==000):
    print("Thank you for playing lottery")
    break
  else:
    rand(k,b)
```

Comment: Every function has it's own namespace. If you assign to `b` ina function it will only change the function's namespace. Use the `global` keyword to set `b` from assign to `b` in the global namespace.

Comment: Use `b = rand(k,b)` to update b after function call.  Globals aren't needed here and are normally discouraged except for selected use cases.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign to `b` the result of the `rand` function, to update its values

```
b = rand(k, b)
```

This is because the `b` inside `rand` is local toe the function, it's not the same, you may use different variables names